# How to write custom messages to MSI log?

Tags: windows-installer

I need to write a custom message to MSI log from my MSI package. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can create a custom action, Win32 DLL recommended. Unfortunately I have only a VBS sample for you, which you can use as a starting point but don't recommend for use in your official release of the package:

```
Function WriteToLog(TextToWrite)
  Const MsgType = &H04000000
  Set rec = Installer.CreateRecord(1)
  rec.StringData(1) = TextToWrite
  Session.Message MsgType, rec
  'Msgbox TextToWrite
WriteToLog = 0
End Function
```